# Setup vscode fortran intellisense to get procedure information from external library/module

Tags: fortran, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode as editor, under Ubuntu system, for programming in Fortran. I decided to build a static library for not compiling it from the beginning each time I compile the main. Now when I write a code using that library, fortran intellisense wants the .mod file to be in the same directory of the main file, but I'd like to avoid that (since it is an archive so I have more .mod files).

I've already setup the fortran intellisense IncludePath to include the folder where the .mod files are present, it doesn't give me an error, but it still cannot find the module in the project, so when I write a procedure, I'm not able to check the arguments and it is quite annoying, is it possible to solve this without copying the .mod files in the same folder of the main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fortran linter (Modern Fortran + fortran IntelliSense) actually compiles your code (without producing any exe) in order to display warnings and find files. This results in a lot of .mod files spawning in your code/ directory which is not convenient at all.
To solve this, you need to tell it where to put the .mod files. This should be done in the workspace settings.

1. Create a “.fmod/” repo at the root of your workspace.
2. Open workspace.code-workspace at the root of your workspace and add the following lines in it:

   ```
   "settings": {
   "fortran.linterExtraArgs": [
       "-J../.fmod", "Wall",  
   ],
   "fortran.includePaths": [
       "../.fmod"
   ],  
   "files.exclude": {
       "**/.fmod": true        },
   ```

   }